# iOS : How to apply audio effect on recorded video

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I am developing an application which require to apply audio effect on recorded video.

I am recording video using GPUImage library. I can successfully done with it. Now, I need to apply audio effect like Chipmunk, Gorila, Large Room, etc.

I looked into Apple's document and it say that AudioEngine can't apply AVAudioUnitTimePitch on Input Node (as Microphone).

For solving this problem, I use following mechanism.

- Record video & audio at same time.
- Play video. While playing video, start AudioEngine on Audio file and apply **AVAudioUnitTimePitch** on it.

  `[playerNode play]; // Start playing audio file with video previ`ew
- Merge video and new effected audio file.

**Problem :**

- User have to preview a full video for audio effect merge. This is not a good solution.
  If I set **volume of playerNode to 0 (zero)**. Then It record mute video.

Please provide any better suggestion to do this things. Thanks in advance.